# haw load user information after login SPA koa.js

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, redux, passport.js, koa

I realized the authorization of the user through the passport (Koa, Mongodb, React, Redux).

```
router.post('/login', function(ctx, next) {

  return passport.authenticate('local', async function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) throw err;

      if (user === false) {
          ctx.status = 401;
          ctx.body = { error: info };
      } else {
          ctx.body = {
              success: true
          };
          await ctx.login(user);
      }
  })(ctx, next);
})
```

If the user logged in, he redirects to the profile page(main page).

```
router.get('/login', function(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.isAuthenticated()) {
      ctx.redirect('/');
  } else {
      ctx.body = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(path.join('build', 'index.html')), 'utf8')
  }
});
```

Since I have a spa I always pass a static file (routing on the client via a react-router)

The problem is that I can not understand how I get information about the user when the profile page is loaded

If I send a ajax-request (feth) from the React-component, then the request for another session id and it is not associated with the user.

Or, I need to do this on the server, but how I might to use the store storage on the server?

How best to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, while it might not be the best way, the easiest way to do this would be to have a section in your html file like..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.currentUser = $$USER$$
</script>
```

And then do a replace on the body.

```
let content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(path.join('build', 'index.html')), 'utf8')
content = content.replace('$$USER$$', JSON.stringify(user))
ctx.body = content
```

In your React app, you can use `window.currentUser`.